# Why isn't Stan Lee in 2015's Fantastic Four?

Tags: marvel, stan-lee, fantastic-four-2015

Does anyone know why Stan Lee doesn't have a cameo in 2015's *Fantastic Four*? Was it scheduling conflicts? Did he not want to be in it? Was it filmed too far away? Was it another reason?

Comment: It doesn't answer your specific question, but [Stan Lee does not appear in a lot of Marvel movies](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/97724/5184).

Comment: Marvel doesn't own the rights to movie adaptations of Fantastic Four.  Fox owns them.  And Marvel has been having an ugly dispute with Fox, so it would be unacceptable for Stan the Man to grace a Fox production with his glorious presence.

Comment: http://moviepilot.com/posts/2014/10/20/marvel-just-quietly-deployed-the-nukes-in-its-war-with-fox-2356058

Comment: http://www.leagle.com/decision/2001156155FSupp2d1_1156/TWENTIETH%20CENTURY%20FOX%20FILM%20CORP.%20v.%20MARVEL%20ENTERPRISES

Comment: http://www.dorkly.com/post/69649/8-insane-behind-the-scenes-things-happening-in-marvel-movies

Comment: So now it seems someone is trying to edit this question in order to advertise the movie. F4 will never cease to disappoint.

Comment: He probably read the script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Stan Lee says](http://www.digitalspy.com/movies/news/a666482/stan-lee-responds-to-fantastic-four-flop-its-because-they-didnt-ask-me-to-cameo.html?rss#~pnab4vajNsIcx4) they didn't ask him to cameo.  Since they didn't ask, he didn't do it.

Here's an interview with Larry King where Stan says it was too far to get to at the time.

Comment: Nice --- I tried to find a direct quote about *Fantastic Four*, but only found the one about *Days of Future Past*.  At least his reasons are consistent between the two. :-)

Comment: Ouch. That hurt *my* feelings. Wish they asked him.

Answer (score 19):

Unlike his appearances in the Marvel Studios-produced films, Stan Lee's appearances in the Fox films are less consistent.  For instance, he did not make a cameo in 2014's *X-Men: Days of Future Past*.

For *Days of Future Past*, he explained:

> **STAN LEE:** As a matter of fact I have never requested a cameo. I love doing them. I’m incredibly happy when somebody asks me to do a cameo but I don’t ask for them. In fact there are times I don’t get them. In the new X-Men movie, I don’t have a cameo because it was shot, I think, somewhere in Europe and I wasn’t able to go there.
>
> But I have a funny theory about it; it also could be they didn’t want me to do a cameo because, without my cameo, the movie will make more money. You are wondering how and I am going to explain that. You see, somebody watches the movie and the movie ends and the person says “Wow, I didn’t see Stan’s Cameo. I must have missed it. So what do they do? Right back to the box office, buy another ticket, and watch the movie again. So I think it’s a big moneymaking ploy on the part of the producers.

([Source](http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/KallarkKentReports/news/?a=100825))

Based on his comments above, and the fact that *Fantastic Four* was [filmed entirely in North America](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1502712/locations), it seems that he simply wasn't asked to appear.  (He explained above that if he were invited to make a cameo and the filming was not abroad, then he would appear.)

One could ask about his physical ability to make a cameo, given that he is 92 years old, but there seem to be no recent changes in his health — at least not reported ones.  In general, he seems to be as sprightly as ever.

**So it seems he wasn't asked by the director or producers, for some unknown reason** — perhaps as part of the "ploy" he mentioned.  He certainly got the OP wondering about it, and so maybe he is right!

While this is pure speculation, the lack of a cameo could be part of the deepening rift between Marvel and Fox (thanks to @WadCheber for this aspect) — see for instance:

- [8 acts of pure spite happening behind the scenes of Marvel movies](http://www.dorkly.com/post/69649/8-insane-behind-the-scenes-things-happening-in-marvel-movies)

It could be that the failure of Fox to extend a cameo invite to Lee could be a salvo in this dispute.  Alternatively, it could be that a cameo was extended but Lee refused it, as a salvo lobbed from the Marvel side.  We may never know.

Comment: Feel free to take whatever you want to take from the articles I linked in my comments on the question itself.  There is a lot of very compelling evidence for the reasons behind Fox snubbing Stan the Man.  Fox and Marvel clearly despise each other.

Comment: Marvel actually cancelled the Fantastic Four comic books, apparently out of sheer spite for Fox.  That's pretty intense.  They seem to have done everything in their power to ensure that the FF movie would be a total train wreck.  It's actually really funny.  You will find a buttload of other articles about the dispute if you google "Marvel Fox dispute".

Comment: @WadCheber : Thanks!  I updated the answer to reflect the Marvel / Fox war.

Comment: @WadCheber Actually, the Fantastic Four comic has been selling very poorly for a long time. It's quite possible that the comic was canceled for this reason and because Marvel was "stream-lining" all its comics for The Secret Wars arc. The Fantastic Four are actually a major part of The Secret Wars, so Marvel isn't totally getting rid of them like some people think.

Comment: @WadCheber Additionally, I wouldn't entirely trust that Dorkly article. Read it's comments to see why.

Comment: Except that he has been shown to have a cameo in the upcoming Fox film Deadpool, so I doubt that it is a rights fight. TPTB in the making of this particular film seem to have wanted to go for a more serious tone and Lee's cameos tend to be very lighthearted

Comment: «he has been shown to have a cameo in the upcoming Fox film Deadpool»: you sure? I know about [a fake cameo photo](http://www.tor.com/2015/08/14/afternoon-roundup-stan-lee-deadpool-cameo-fake/). Do you know of a real one?

Answer (score -3):

It could be because the 2015 Fantastic Four was an abysmal film.

The earlier 2005 version had its faults, but had a fairly lighthearted approach that meant it could get away with it. By comparison, the 2015 version has few redeeming features. You only have to look at the Rotten Tomatoes score (9%) to realise that it's a dull turkey.

Someone suggested that the ultimate cameo would be for Stan Lee to walk in on Thor as a cleaner, casually lift Mjolnir, clean under it, put it down and walk out...

Comment: Stan casually giving Mjolnir a spritz and wipe would be cool beyond reconning. Putting it down a bit to the left so he could wipe under it would give Thor new concerns; Mr. Lee should voice Beta Ray Bill!

Comment: F4 was a really terrible film but Mr. Lee has cameoed in several bad Marvel movies so I doubt quality was the issue.